# Prove that $\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\frac{y^2}{z^2}+\frac{z^2}{x^2}\geq \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{z^2}+\frac{z^2}{y^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}{z^2}}$

Tags: inequality

How would I prove that $\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\frac{y^2}{z^2}+\frac{z^2}{x^2}\geq \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{z^2}+\frac{z^2}{y^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}{z^2}}$ using AM-GM. This inequality seems a bit odd since $\frac{x^2}{z^2}$ appears twice.

Comment: Don't change the question completely midway. If you have a different problem, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = \dfrac{x^2}{y^2}, b = \dfrac{y^2}{z^2}, c = \dfrac{z^2}{x^2}\implies abc = 1, a,b,c > 0$. Thus We prove: $a+b+c \ge \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{b}}+ \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{c}}= \sqrt{a(b+c)}+\sqrt{b(a+c)}$. By AM-GM: $RHS \le \dfrac{a+(b+c)}{2}+\dfrac{b+(a+c)}{2}=a+b+c= LHS $. We're done.

**Note:** This answer is for the original question, but OP somehow edited it and wrote a new one.

Comment: Yes, I've rollbacked to a previous version.